# Adding variable value into expression

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to convert some future date to epoch number on Ubuntu Mate 20.04.

So I decide to write this code:

```
daysAmount="10"   
endDate=$(date +"%b %_d %Y" -d "+$daysAmount days")   
epochNum=$(date -d "$endDate" +%s)
```

The first two lines are working well, but I'm not getting anything on `epochNum=`.

Is it OK to write another variable inside `$(date)` like I have?
If not, how can I make this thing work?

I also tried `endDate=$(date +"%b %_d %Y" -d "+$daysAmount days" +%s)` but that did not work either.

Comment: What operating system are you using? I am guessing Linux based on your `date` format, but please [edit] your question and clarify that. Anyway, the second line should give an error. Are you saying you don't get `date: extra operand ‘+%s’`?

Comment: Your second line gives me: `date: illegal time format` - on OS X

Comment: @Greenonline this can't be OSX or macOS because that uses BSD `date` which doesn't not support `-d`. Which of course just highlights why it is important to always mention your OS.

Comment: @terdon i edited the code and the question. I forgot to remove that +%s from my second line. 
Now the code is how i run it

Comment: That code works exactly as expected. What is it that doesn't work for you? What happens if you copy/paste the _exact_ code block from your question into a terminal and then run `echo $epochNum`? Is this maybe part of a larger script or a loop and you are running the `echo $epochNum` outside it?

Comment: @terdon i just found why...... 
Because im in EU and my machine is using Cyrilic output for mounts ( instead Dec-for december, it is Дек-Декември )

I test it on a VM wit US type of showing the information and it start working magically :D

Comment: If you've solved your issue, it would be great if you could please post an answer with your solution so we can mark this as answered. If not, please [edit] and show us what you are doing in full. We need to see error messages and all the details. You can get this to work in any locale.

Comment: @terdon i did not get any error messages. Just empty line.
During the the test i did not use "set +x" option in code

I will post an answer. If you are interested how to make it work on different languages will be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run commands with a temporary locale. This should solve your issue:

```
daysAmount="10"   
endDate=$(LC_ALL=C date +"%b %_d %Y" -d "+$daysAmount days")   
epochNum=$(LC_ALL=C date -d "$endDate" +%s)
```

Comment: That work as a charm!
Thanx allot!

Answer (score 0):

Manage to make it work.

Check your date language before converting to epoch number.
If your name of the mount is different from the us alphabet like the example of "date" command here:

```
1.11.2021 (пн) 14:47:59 EET
```

The conversion will not work.

In different machine where "date" shows like this (us alphabet):

```
Mon Nov  1 14:47:45 EET 2021
```

the code was working perfectly fine

---

For a working example on machines with different languages see:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675661/499362